# Vtiger CRM How to disbale the module export option from module manager

Tags: php, smarty, crm, vtiger

I am developing a custom module and i need to disable the module export option from the settings->module manager.I like to do this to prevent downloading my module.Please help me hide/remove the export option from my custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Just update `vtiger_tab` table and set `customized` column to `0` value of your module